# prevent proftpd to rename directoy on create

Tags: linux, ftp, inotify

**description:** I asked a question in stackoverflow ([Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953899/how-exactly-ftp-data-channel-works?noredirect=1)) about how FTP server works in data channel, I did not get my answer,however I find out that there are several FTP server, My server use proftpd with default config(I think it's direct Admin default config actually)

**Problem** well, I don't want this, **I want FTP Create directory directly without any renaming or anything else**, but I don't know how to configure proftpd to work like this

any ideas ?

**edit**: apparently **this only happen when a directory is created**, question updated

**edit 2**: I ended up changing inotify logic to support ProFTPd directory creation, AFAIK this behavior become default since a security bug, but still I'd like to know if there is any workaround

Comment: You can try this turning off feature. I have not tried this . http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HiddenStores.html. Additionally you can write a logic in your inotify script to fix this issue

Comment: @StackPlayer yes I already checked the link you gave it to me, but the thing is the default setting is off and I don't have any configuration of this directive in my config file,also "hidden stores" directive stores file like .in.filename, but mine stores like .dstXXVxxT. unfortunately there is no time to change logic in inotify(stability issues)